# Retrieve ng-model value from href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure if the way i phrased my question makes sense, sorry if it doesn't. Basically, what I want to ask is, is it possible to retrieve value from href into controller. Example,

I have 2 href

```
 <a href="" ng-model="a">Download1</a>
 <a href="" ng-model="b">Download2</a>
```

So, when download1 is clicked, it will store 'a' into a variable in my controller. Is that possible?

Comment: I think it's better to read the URL with [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` for that.

```
<a href="" ng-click="download('a')">Download1</a>
```

So, in your Controller you must have the download function like this.

```
$scope.download = function(value){
    console.log(value)
}
```

and you do the same thing for *b* only in the html part because you can use the same function, which is download().

```
<a href="" ng-click="download('b')">Download2</a>
```

Now if you click Download1 you will get

> a

and when you click Download2 you will get

> b

Comment: Cool, exactly what I want. But how do you make it to be available outside the function? I am getting undefined when I console log it outside the function. @holydragon

Comment: Is it caused by asynchronous ? How do i fix that